# Clear the contents of an EditText Field once button is pressed

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-edittext, android-handler

I am creating a simple app which automatically triggers a button `b` once the contents of an `EditText` field called `a` contains a key phrase.  I am wanting to clear the contents of the edit text field automatically say after 2 seconds.  Is there a easy way to implement this into my code below?

```
public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener
{

private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";

/* Keyword we are looking for to activate menu */
private static final String KEYPHRASE = "open voice command";   //adjust this keyphrase!

private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;

ListView lv;
TextView tv;
EditText a;
Button b;
Button c;

Boolean isDone = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);

    // Prepare the data for UI
    captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
            .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
    a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
    c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Blogin);

    // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
    // so we execute it in async task

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);
                File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                setupRecognizer(assetDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            if (result != null) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                        .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
            } else {
                switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
//line added.../////////////////////////
    a.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("open voice command")) {
                //
                //Do your stuff here OR button.performClick()
                //

                //DELAY
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!isDone) {
                            b.performClick();
                            isDone = true;
                        }
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
////////////////////////////////////////
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    recognizer.cancel();
    recognizer.shutdown();
}

/**
 * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
 * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
 * for final result in onResult.
 */
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis == null)
        return;

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername)).setText(text);
}

/**
 * This callback is called when we stop the recognizer.
 */
@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("");
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername)).setText("");
    if (hypothesis != null) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    //a.setText((String) tv.getText());
        //tv = TextView.getText().toString();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
}

/**
 * We stop recognizer here to get a final result
 */
@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    if (!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(KWS_SEARCH))
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}

private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
    recognizer.stop();

    // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
    if (searchName.equals(KWS_SEARCH))
        recognizer.startListening(searchName);
    else
        recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);

    String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(caption);
}

private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
    // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
    // of different kind and switch between them

    recognizer = defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))

                    // To disable logging of raw audio comment out this call (takes a lot of space on the device)
            .setRawLogDir(assetsDir)

                    // Threshold to tune for keyphrase to balance between false alarms and misses
            .setKeywordThreshold(1e-45f)

                    // Use context-independent phonetic search, context-dependent is too slow for mobile
            .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)

            .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);

    /** In your application you might not need to add all those searches.
     * They are added here for demonstration. You can leave just one.
     */

    // Create keyword-activation search.
    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);

}

@Override
public void onError(Exception error) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(error.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void onTimeout() {
    switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}

//Assign button clicks to go to a new activity:
public void onButtonClick_1(View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bVoice){
        String str_1 = a.getText().toString();

        //Go to the relevant page if any part of the phrase or word entered in the 'EditText' field contains 'command' which is not case sensitive
        if (str_1.toLowerCase().contains("command")) {
            Intent userintent = new Intent(PocketSphinxActivity.this, Gvoice.class);

            startActivity(userintent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

//Added this to clear the 'open voice command' text when pressing back from a activity window
//This at the moment seems to only work when typing the command, If I use speech to text to say'open voice command
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    isDone = false;
    a.setText("");
}

}
```

Additionally, due to using a boolean method, if I go back to this activity using the back button etc in my app, it does not seem to trigger the option again.  Is there a way to cause it to trigger `b` again if I return back to the same window/activity?

I'll really appreciate some useful help in modifying part of my code shown above.

Comment: I tested your code on my end. Commented out those not related to the main concern. And I managed to receive the correct behavior. When `EditText` has "open voice command", clears the `EditText` and starts handler with delay of 500ms. Get back to it from an Activity, nothing happens. Unless you type in "open voice command" in the `EditText` again or you press `Button b` and "command" exists in the `EditText`. Checked the flow, nothing other than the handler runs `performClick()`. Nothing changes the text to that will trigger the handler. I'm not sure how you're getting that kind of behavior.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer and post the edited code I have from you. Most of it is commented out. Test running it on your end.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you're actually doing it already on your code. The only thing that I don't understand is as to why do you have the `boolean isDone`? Have you tried removing it? Since if you already cleared the `EditText`, even if it does go through `onTextChanged` again, it wont pass the first condition again (Here I'm presuming that `b`s action is to clear the text of `a`).

For the text checking, I think you can use androids [TextUtils.equals()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#equals(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) :

```
TextUtils.equals(s, "open voice command");
```

> EDIT

Okay. So I re-analyzed your post and your comments and ended up with this flow of behavior.

The First time the activity runs, when you type in "open voice command" in  `EditText a`, `Button b` will be automatically clicked and will proceed to starting an activity and MUST clear `EditText a`. Pressing back to the activity that contains both `EditText a` and `Button b`, you want the `EditText a` `onTextChangeListener` to still function.

With those in mind, I ended up modifying your code as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText a;
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize Views
        a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);

        // Initialize listeners
        a.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (TextUtils.equals(s, "open voice command")) {
                    Log.d("SAMPLE", ">>>>>>> Running handler!....");
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            a.setText(null);
                            b.performClick();
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

When I type in "open voice command" in `EditText a`, is automatically gets cleared and calls the `performClick()` for `Button b`. After I get back to the activity. Nothing happens, the handler doesn't run since the text value of `EditText a` is empty. The handler will only trigger again if you type in "open voice command".

> EDIT 2

Here is the code I am running. I just commented out most of the codes that are not related to the concern on your post. I'm getting the correct behavior you are aiming for.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {

    private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";

    /* Keyword we are looking for to activate menu */
    private static final String KEYPHRASE = "open voice command";   //adjust this keyphrase!

    private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;

    ListView lv;
    TextView tv;
    EditText a;
    Button b;
    Button c;

    Boolean isDone = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Prepare the data for UI
//        captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
//        captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
//        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
//                .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

//        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
//        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
        a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
//        c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Blogin);

        // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
        // so we execute it in async task

//        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
//            @Override
//            protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
//                try {
//                    Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);
//                    File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
//                    setupRecognizer(assetDir);
//                } catch (IOException e) {
//                    return e;
//                }
//                return null;
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
//                if (result != null) {
//                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
//                            .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
//                } else {
//                    switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
//                }
//            }
//        }.execute();
//line added.../////////////////////////
        a.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("open voice command")) {
                    //
                    //Do your stuff here OR button.performClick()
                    //

                    //DELAY
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (!isDone) {
                                b.performClick();
                                isDone = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
//        recognizer.cancel();
//        recognizer.shutdown();
    }

    /**
     * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
     * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
     * for final result in onResult.
     */
//    @Override
//    public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
//        if (hypothesis == null)
//            return;
//
//        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
//        //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
//        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername)).setText(text);
//    }

    /**
     * This callback is called when we stop the recognizer.
     */
//    @Override
//    public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
//        //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("");
//        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername)).setText("");
//        if (hypothesis != null) {
//            String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
//            makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//
//            //a.setText((String) tv.getText());
//            //tv = TextView.getText().toString();
//        }
//    }

    /**
     * We stop recognizer here to get a final result
     */
    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
//        if (!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(KWS_SEARCH))
//            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    }

    private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
//        recognizer.stop();
//
//        // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
//        if (searchName.equals(KWS_SEARCH))
//            recognizer.startListening(searchName);
//        else
//            recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);
//
//        String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
//        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(caption);
    }

    private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
        // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
        // of different kind and switch between them

//        recognizer = defaultSetup()
//                .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
//                .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
//
//                // To disable logging of raw audio comment out this call (takes a lot of space on the device)
//                .setRawLogDir(assetsDir)
//
//                // Threshold to tune for keyphrase to balance between false alarms and misses
//                .setKeywordThreshold(1e-45f)
//
//                // Use context-independent phonetic search, context-dependent is too slow for mobile
//                .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)
//
//                .getRecognizer();
//        recognizer.addListener(this);

        /** In your application you might not need to add all those searches.
         * They are added here for demonstration. You can leave just one.
         */

        // Create keyword-activation search.
//        recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);
    }

//    @Override
//    public void onError(Exception error) {
//        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(error.getMessage());
//    }

//    @Override
//    public void onTimeout() {
//        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
//    }

    //Assign button clicks to go to a new activity:
    public void onButtonClick_1(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.b) {
            String str_1 = a.getText().toString();

            //Go to the relevant page if any part of the phrase or word entered in the 'EditText' field contains 'command' which is not case sensitive
            if (str_1.toLowerCase().contains("command")) {
                Intent userintent = new Intent(PocketSphinxActivity.this, Gvoice.class);
                startActivity(userintent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    //Added this to clear the 'open voice command' text when pressing back from a activity window
    //This at the moment seems to only work when typing the command, If I use speech to text to say'open voice command
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isDone = false;
        a.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: `b`s action is to actually open a new activity @McAwesomville.  The issue I was having before was that I want button `b` to be pressed autmatically once after 500ms.  However without using the boolean option I was getting it to trigger continuously every 500ms.  I have declared the `boolean isDone = false` at the start of my java.  At the moment it is doing what I want but when I return back to the main activity using the back button or through a button press of another activity it shows the EditText field still containing the entry which I do not wish to see and want to be empty.

Comment: I see. I still can't get too much of the details, but why not set `isDone=true` in the `onResume` of your activity?

Comment: setting `isDone=true` no longer triggers a button press automatically

Comment: Sorry. Set it to `false`, rather. :)

Comment: I don't think that will work as it will constantly trigger the button every 500ms which is definitely what I do not want. any other ideas?

Comment: So you only have to run it once every time you get back to that activity?

Comment: I'm gonna have a try at your code and let you know what I find out. :)

Comment: Check my edit @NMC and let me know what's up. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your time, i'll get back to you soon on whether this is working and hopefully it does and then I will close the case by accepting your answer.  Where do you suggest I place the code in my java file.. @McAwesomville?

Comment: No worries. I just modified your code. Try to replace the ones you coded with mine? The only code I changed is the code inside `onTextChanged()`. Cheers!

Comment: by the way have you got any experience with googles voice api @McAwesomville.  As an individual app I can get speech to text working perfectly fine but when I use it as a separate activity within the app discussed on this page, I instantly get a message 'Can't Open Microphone'

Comment: Sorry. I haven't tried using that yet. But after doing a [quick research](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tmobile-galaxy-s6-edge/help/ok-google-microphone-please-help-t3113584), it seems it's just a concern with the device itself somehow. Cheers! :D

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it doesn't apply in my case since my individual app works fine but when combined it doesn't..? Just wondering if it's an API issue etc

Comment: Unfortunately tried your code @McAwesomville with some corrections to id names etc but it continuously bring up the Gvoice activity every 500ms and wont let me do anything else.

Comment: That is odd. Because the only reason that the `Handler` should run is if the `EditText` has the `open voice command` text inside. It seems there is something else triggering your `Handler`

Comment: I have updated the full java file now, if you don't mind can you please double check and let me know where in the code I have gone wrong @McAwesomville

Comment: Hey @McAwesomville, have you had a chance to look at the full code I uploaded a couple of days ago?

Comment: I did. I mentioned in the comment on your post. Do try running the simple code on EDIT 2. I commented out the other codes and I was able to get the correct behavior from your code alone.

Comment: How was it? Were you able to try it? I suggest creating a dummy project to simply try thr behavior. On how I see it, it seems you already have the behavior you need. I needn't edit your code to achieve it. @NMC

Comment: Yeah not much luck, the code you provided @McAwesomville keeps giving me an error for the public class 'pocketsphinxactivity must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method...'  A have also corrected the button assignments etc

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried going to the error then press alt+space > implement methods? Just to get the necessary override methods.

Comment: Umm, yeah.  Having a closer look at your code it is pretty much what I already had.  The issue is when implementing pocketsphinx.  It's a shame there aren't too many people on here that have much experience with speech to text and voice commands api.